# how to hide column from the Datagrid/table in flutter from a button?

Tags: flutter, dart

anyone knows how to hide column from button in data grid or a table in flutter,
I am not getting the exact solution for this, I have to make table with 21 columns and 10 rows, and 10 buttons would be connected to 21 columns and I do not know how to resolve this error